# How to identify processes consuming high memory in beanstalk aws app Django

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

a few days ago an instance of my beanstalk environment is showing a status warning due to high memory usage (about 95%), I used htop to try to identify the problem, but I couldn't interpret the output very well (image)

[image]

Can you give me suggestions to identify this problem?